# Quadratic term and categorical predictors

Tags: r, interaction, glmm, quadratic-form

I have  a quick question about the use of quadratic term in GLMM. Can I use it with categorical variables?

I read somewhere that its use is restricted to continuous predictors and the thing is that I have a model consisting of many categorical predictors and only two continuous predictors (age and stimulus frequency) which are not significant.

Appreciating your input.

Shad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a categorical variable, you would split that up into a set of dummy (indicator) variables before adding it to your model. So you have a set of variables that are either 0 or 1. What happens when you square that? $0^2=0$ and $1^2=1$. So the square term is an exact copy of the original variable, and it won't add anything to your model and will thus be dropped due to perfect collinearity.

You can add quadratic terms for your age and stimulus variables and leave the categorical variables as a set of dummy variables. Especially the effect of age, when it covers a large range, is likely to be non-linear.